# $e^{\varphi -1}$ characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

So I am trying to figure out whether $e^{\varphi-1}$ is a characteristic function given that $\varphi$ is. I know that linear combinations of characteristic functions and the real part of a characteristic function are characteristic functions. 
I would like to figure this one out by myself so just some small hints would be appreciated. How do I chose the random variable $Y$ for this function?

Comment: Can you find a sequence of characteristic functions that converges pointwise to $e^{\varphi-1}$?

Comment: would $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(\varphi -1)^i}{i!}$ suffice?

Comment: That would be the natural candidate. See Theorem 8.10 here: https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/characteristic.pdf

Comment: So am I correct that the argument would be as follows:

Comment: $(\varphi-1)$ is a characteristic function (because 1 is the characteristic function of Ber(0)?) and hence $(\varphi-1)^i $ is a characteristic function ( use i.i.d. copies of $X$ where $X$ is the variable associated with $\varphi$). As a result $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(\varphi -1)^i}{i!}$ is a characteristic function because it is a linear combination of characteristic functions. So $e^{\varphi-1}$ is the pointwise limit of characteristic functions. Because $e^{(x-1)}$ is continuos at 0 the statement follows?

Comment: Sorry but $\varphi-1$ is **never** a characteristic function hence what the exchanges in the comments above do is to send you into a deadend. Rather, note that $$e^{\varphi-1}=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac1{n!e}\varphi^n,$$ and marvel at the fact that the RHS is a barycenter of the characteristic functions $\varphi^n$. (Of course, all this suggests a way to construct a random variable of characteristic function $e^{\varphi-1}$ using i.i.d. copies of random variables of characteristic function $\varphi$ and an independent Poisson random variable with parameter $1$.)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose Y is an rv that has the cf $\phi$. 
Then consider X = $Y1 + Y2 + ... + Y_P$ where Y1, Y2, ... are iid copies of Y and P follows Poisson(1).
Thus, $E(e^{itX}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty E(e^{itX};P=k) \frac{e^{-1}}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \phi^k\frac{e^{-1}}{k!} = e^{\phi-1} $
Thus, $e^{\phi-1} $ is the characteristic function of X.